# Solving $\int_0^{\infty}\!\sqrt{x}\,J_1(a\sqrt{x})\cos(\omega x)\,dx$ and $\int_0^{\infty}\!\sqrt{x}\,J_1(a\sqrt{x})\sin(\omega x)\,dx$

Tags: special-functions, definite-integrals

I should solve the following integrals:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\!\sqrt{x}\,J_1(a\sqrt{x})\cos(\omega x)\,dx$$

and

$$\int_0^{\infty}\!\sqrt{x}\,J_1(a\sqrt{x})\sin(\omega x)\,dx$$

with $a, \omega >0$.

I cannot find them in Gradshteyn & Ryzhik.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: For the first integral, you can have the closed form $-\frac{a}{2\omega^2}\cos \left( {\frac {{a}^{2}}{4\omega}} \right)$ and for the second $\frac{a}{2\omega^2}\sin\left( {\frac {{a}^{2}}{4\omega}} \right)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even the special case $a=1,\omega=0$
$$
\int _{0}^{s}\!\sqrt {x}\;{{\rm J}_1\left(\sqrt {x}\right)}{dx}=-2\,s\;
{{\rm J}_0\left(\sqrt {s}\right)}+4\,
{{\rm J}_1\left(\sqrt {s}\right)}\sqrt {s}
$$
has limsup $+\infty$ and liminf $-\infty$ as $s \to \infty$.

So why do you think the case $\omega>0$ converges?

Comment: Thanks! I think you are right. It is not convergent at all.